# Why Visual Studio Code settings don't get apply

Tags: visual-studio-code

In `files:exclude` I've added the `**\.bak` both to the workspace and the user settings
[image]

but the bak files are still showing

[image]

looking at `settings.json` in `.vscode` shows the rule was added

[image]

Any suggestions on why these files are still showing?

Comment: try the string `**/*.bak`, you don't have a `.bak` file

Comment: @rioV8 it worked thanks. Can you elaborate why the other rules without the `*` like `**/.git` are working?

Comment: `.git` is the folder where GIT stores the repository, it is the full file name

Answer (score 0):

You're only excluding all files and folders named exactly `.bak`. If you want to exclude all files with the extension `.bak`, you need to add the wildcard character (`*`) before the extension:

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.bak": true
    }
}
```